# My Docker Compose File is not working properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

hi how are you guys i have 2 docker-compose file but both files are not run properly i face this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ3ri.png)
error please tell me any body how to fix it i give u a compose file content

**(COMPOSE FILE 1)**

```
db:
  build: ./mysql
  volumes:
    - /opt/containers/personal/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
web:
  build: ./web
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - /opt/containers/personal/php:/var/www/html
  links:
    - db:db
```

**(COMPOSE FILE 2)**

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /opt/containers/personal/nginx/certs:/certs
    depends_on: 
      - web
    networks:
      - webdbnet
  web:
    build: ./web
    volumes:
      # Example of host volume mounted in container
      # - /opt/containers/personal/php:/var/www/html
      # Example of docker volume mounted in container
      - web-data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - webdbnet
  db:
    # build: ./mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - /opt/containers/personal/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - webdbnet

networks:
  webdbnet:

volumes:
  web-data:
```

**(AND THIS IS MY BUILD DOCKER FILE CONTENT)**

```
FROM php:7-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      libfreetype6-dev \
      libjpeg-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && a2enmod rewrite expires \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli opcache iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
       --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
       --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
       --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt mysqli

COPY index.html /var/www/html/
COPY index.php  /var/www/html/
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Check the error message - you have the wrong version of PHP installed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running the wrong version of PHP for mcrypt.

Try replacing

```
FROM php:7-apache
```

with

```
FROM php:7.2.14-apache-stretch
```

In your build file.

`php:7-apache` is taking you to the latest version, which is 7.3.1 and mcrypt seems to want 7.2.*

Comment: thanks bro u r great bro but i have one more problem see this bro

Answer (score 0):

When you use official image for php and for this example try to install `pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1` after that command you'll need to add this line to

```
RUN pecl install mcrypt

RUN echo "extension=mcrypt.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini
```

Only extension installed via `docker-php-ext-install` are not required to enable with *.so file

I hope this helps..

Comment: bro it did not work i face many errors can u write compose file for me?